# Open Graph approved - but does only work for admins

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I submitted my app to facebook and it got approved, i am using open Graph which also is approved. The Open Graph is posting actions to user activity log and the problem is that it's only working for administrators, when i try with a regular user it doens't post to its activity log. The app page is not in sandbox mode, it's set to allow its live features to the general public.

So i don't really know what to do anymore, the app page is fully approved and yet i have this issue, which doesn't make any sence to me, any other with the same issue?

Comment: Have you gathered the `publish_actions` permission from non-admin users?

Comment: Yes the user approves permissions for the app to post on their behalf, what do you mean by permission from non-admin users? Is that a setting to adjust?

Comment: Is the user you test this with an admin of your app or not?

Comment: I have tested with my self which im an admin and when i does that it do post to the activity log, then i've tested with a non-admin user so a regular user and with that one it doesn't post to the activity log.

Comment: when i look at facebook insight i see i have a lot of API error one error has 100% failure rate, and that is: POST user/external_edge, can that have anything to do with this issue? I don't know what that error mean as there are no description about it